# Laravel HasManyThrough relation empty output

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need help with Laravel eloquent model relations. I have **three tables**:

**items**

```
item_id
slideshowID
```

**slideshows**

```
slideshow_id
```

**images**

```
image_id
slideshowID
```

I spent all day trying to get it to work, I just can't.
What I want is, for each item to have its own slideshow of images.

**item model**

```
public function images(){   
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\image','App\slideshow','slideshow_id','slideshowID','slideshowID'
    );}
```

**controller**

```
$items=item::with('images')->get();
return \View::make('home')->with('items', $items);
```

**View**

```
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <div class='item' data-categoryid='{{$item->categoryID}}'>
        <div class='item-image'>
            @foreach($item->images as $image)
                <img src='{{URL::asset($image->path)}}' data-image-id='{{$image->image_id}}' style='display:none'>
            @endforeach 
        </div>
        <div class='item-name'>{{$item->name}}</div>
        <div class='item-price'>Od {{$item->price}}&euro;</div>
            <button class='btn-blue'>Več...</button>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Query

```
select `images`.*, `slideshows`.`slideshow_id` from `images` inner join `slideshows` on `slideshows`.`slideshow_id` = `images`.`slideshowID` where `slideshows`.`slideshow_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" array(7) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(6) [4]=> int(3) [5]=> int(4) [6]=> int(5) }
```

Output - **empty images array**

```
{"items_id":1,"code":"999","name":"koledar","description":"","slideshowID":1,"stock":999,"price":5.5,"categoryID":2,"images":[]}
```

**EDIT**
I managed to get some images out, but they are wrong ones.

```
Item: 3
Slideshow fk:2
Slideshow id:3
9 images/bon2.jpg 
Slideshow id:3
10 images/bon.jpg
```

It always gets the slideshow equal to item's ID. I have tried to add to item model **protected $foreignKey='slideshowID'** but doesn't change a thing

Comment: I also tried with $this->belongsToMany and I also get empty array, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close just need to change a little bit like this **`slideshows`** model you need to add the primary key there

```
protected $primaryKey = 'slideshow_id';//https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L56
```

This is needed because when you are calling **`hasManyThrough`** see here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L875-L886 it's calling

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, I do think I did that in my slideshow model but maybe I commented /* */ it for some reason, I am at home now, I will try tommorow and report. Thanks!

Comment: I added protected $primaryKey to item,slideshow model, I do get images on output, but I get wrong images. See edit

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had the database tables set up wrong. Instead if having tables like this:

**items**

```
item_id
slideshowID
```

**slideshows**

```
slideshow_id
```

images

```
image_id
slideshowID
```

I changed them to

**items**

```
item_id
```

**slideshows**

```
slideshow_id
item_id
```

images

```
image_id
slideshowID
```